# Angular2 Material Vs Bootstrap?

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, bootstrap-4

This could be a naive question but please help me on this as I'm about to create a new application and I am stucked on this whether I should go with **angular2 material or bootstrap.**

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't give advice on choice of library to use. This question is considered offtopic here.

Comment: @Senthe I have asked question in past regarding libraries. I believe stack overflow supports you in making right choices. Thankx

Comment: This is opinion based. Both with have benefits and downsides. Some people may prefer one to another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you go with Material

- Better UI & UX;
- Built for Angular;
- Lot's off callbacks;
- Very good docs;

And they are still working on many features;

Bootstrap for Angular is really bad now; I'm waiting for an effect on collapse for more than 9 months...

Comment: I would agree.  The look and feel is much better.  But to me the biggest drawback is forms and form validation.  Bootstrap has straight forward approach while material seems to be much more complicated.

Comment: It's not that complicated if you get used to it.

Comment: What about components like carousels etc? I can't find anything for angular2 but plenty for bootstrap. Is there a place where I can find components like that for a mobile app?

Comment: @displayname Well, if you are new to javascript / ts then you can find another 3rd part component, plenty of them if you google it, else do like me, Using Material Tabs i've been able to create a very nice Carousel, better than the bootstrap one.

Comment: I have been trying to test Angular Material with two different Angular projects, one build with Angular CLI and the second with Visual Studio's Aspnet core 2.0 template. With both, I have not been successful to get started with a simple page. It's been quite a frustrating experience going through workarounds before I can start running the server. For start, npm instaling @angular/material, asks to upgrade you Angular version to 5.0.0. When I did, then it complained about the cli not being 2.3.1 or greater when it was 5.0.0. I had to do some workarounds. In one tutorial I was following, to impl